# Proper way to compare decimal values in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, decimal

I have this spec that checks for the expected number:

```
  expect(animal_cost).to eq(0.7771118644067795e5)
```

I get an error that says:

```
  expected: 77711.18644067795
        got: 0.7771118644067795e5
```

As you can see, the number I got is the same as the one I expected so I'm confused why this is failing. How can I set the spec?

`animal_cost.class` is a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [animal_cost] equals `0.7771118644067795e5` [...] it's a `BigDecimal`

It's a floating point issue. Your `BigDecimal` with a value of 0.7771118644067795e5 has an *exact* value of:

```
77711.18644067795
```

The float `77711.18644067795` on the other hand has an actual value of: (like most languages, Ruby truncates floats)

```
77711.186440677949576638638973236083984375
```

Depending on the comparison, these values might or might not be treated as "equal":

```
d = BigDecimal('0.7771118644067795e5')
f = 0.7771118644067795e5

d == f      #=> true
f == d      #=> true

d.eql?(f)   #=> true
f.eql?(d)   #=> false
```

The latter returns `false` because that's how [`Float#eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Float.html#eql-3F-method) works:

> #### eql?(obj) → true or false
>
> Returns `true` only if `obj` is a `Float` with the same value as `float`.

In order to make the test pass with the exact value, you should use a `BigDecimal` instead of a float:

```
expect(animal_cost).to eq(BigDecimal('0.7771118644067795e5'))
```

Personally, I'd avoid such examples because you're (apparently) copying the result into the expectation. It's not at all obvious whether this value is correct or not. (a "cost" with 11 decimal places seems wrong to me) Try to change your example data to get a comprehensible result and maybe also a "whole" number like e.g. 70,000.

Comment: Indeed. Depending on the currency (JPY, GBP, USD) of  `animal.cost` you should only ever need a maximum of three decimal places, and anything more than that is probably needless precision for the purposes of the RSpec test.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to verify floats using rspec is to use the `be_within` matcher. Floats cannot be represented completely mathematically accurate in binary. There are bound to be some rounding errors.

In your case one would write:

```
expect(animal_cost).to be_within(0.001).of(0.7771118644067795e5)
```